# Why is my bootstrap navbar not displaying inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my html using bootstrap (I'm sure bootstrap is installed correctly)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Rebar</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When it displays the three links are being displayed as block elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because in Bootstrap the css for li is this:

```
.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

But for me the menu seems to appear correctly. See snippet, but only on a full page. On mobile devices it will behave like a block element since the screen doesn't have room to show them inline.

EDIT: Updated the snippit to work as requested (see comments below this answer)

```css
.navbar .container-fluid>.navbar-header {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.nav>li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Rebar</a>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I've been testing in mobile... so I guess thats the problem. Is there a way to force it to display inline on mobile?

Comment: You can write css media queries to change how it looks on different sizes and screens.

Comment: @nash I updated the example in my post with a media query with some css changes. Probably not the best way to do it exactly, but it should get you on your way.

Answer (score 9):

Currently on Bootstrap 4. The flex layout seems to be columnar by default in my ecosystem as well.

The most direct override for this use case:

```
.navbar-nav { 
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into this issue with BS4.  Learned I needed to add `navbar-expand-lg` class to my nav.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
```

Comment: This also fixed the issue for me using Bootstrap 5 - thanks!

Comment: Worked for me as well, but this involves stablishing a breakpoint. Could there be a 'cleaner' way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying the other answers are incorrect in any way, but all that is really needed to accomplish the original question is this entry in the subtheme's CSS file:

```
.nav.navbar-nav li {
    float: left;
}
```

It should be noted that the class(s) before the li will vary depending on selections in the Appearance section of the theme and other factors. For example, right out of the box the class would have been .menu.nav li

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem.
Try this:

```
.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

It worked for me

Comment: Best and correct answer in terms of staying within the rules of the framework. This worked for me like a charm. The other answer are propably working as well. However, this is the road that I've picked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want like this way **[check this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qo30jgjh/)**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" id="topnavbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top_navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="top_navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently on Bootstrap 4, the inline navbar can be achieved by adding class "nav-item" on list elements and class "nav-link" on a tags like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Rebar</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class= "nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class= "nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class= "nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.

So if your nav class is like that

change lg to sm or if -sm then change into -lg

Answer (score 0):

You can make an inline `navbar` easily with this custom `CSS` class:

**Css:**

```
.nav.inline-navbar>li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now use it in your **Html:**

```
.....
<ul class="nav navbar-nav inline-navbar">
   ......
</ul>
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quuick modify, I add `style="display: inline"` in the below position:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportContent" style="display: inline">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="toggleContent('single')">One Line Param</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="toggleContent('multi')">Multi Line Param</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just simply add this into your CSS and get the elements in one line

```
.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet below, the highlighted line used to be `<div class="nav navbar-nav">`. In this case, just removing 'navbar-nav' solved the problem to me.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top" id="homehead">
        <img class="navbar-brand" src="" height=50 width=50 alt="">

THIS LINE-> <div class="nav">

            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">Link1<span
                    class="sr-only"></span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">Link2</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">Link3</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="">Link4</a>
        </div>
```