# Why is my bootstrap navbar brand not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>


    </style>
  </head>


<body>


<div class="navbar navbar-default">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon bar"></span>
            <span class="icon bar"></span>
            <span class="icon bar"></span>
        </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyBinge</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

    </div>

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">get started</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tell us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about this project</a></li>
</ul>




  </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to figure out why my navbar brand is not in line with the rest of the navbar content. I already tried the solutions in this post [Why is my bootstrap navbar not displaing inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365057/why-is-my-bootstrap-navbar-not-displaing-inline)

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't close the div before the ul. Include the ul with class .nav .navbar-nav like this

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">get     
       started</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tell us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about this project</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using Wordpress with Bootstrap 3, you need to add the class above to the navigation array             <?php /* Primary navigation */
            wp_nav_menu( array(
              'menu' => 'top_menu',
              'depth' => 2,
              'container' => false,
              'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
              //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
              'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
            ?>

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself. 
I closed the div of  `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">` before the ul list. I'm realy new to coding but I hope this can help someone