# Navbar is not displaying inline

Tags: html, css, navbar, inline

My Navbar is not displaying inline.
When change code: `.nav li a {...}` to `.nav li{...}` it is in line, but all the css functions disappear from the class=nav in HTML.
I tried to add `ul.nav{display: inline-block;}` but it does nothing.

I hope I explained it well, I was trying to figure it out since yesterday...

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
}

.nav li a {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 24px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400, 600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Smart-Home</title>
  </head>
<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> O firmie </a></li>
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> Produkty </a></li>
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> Nasi partnerzy </a></li>
        <li><a href ="indexKontakt.html"> Kontakt </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can just add this to the CSS:

```
.nav li{
  display: inline; //or inline-block
}
```

Working version here- https://jsfiddle.net/2rovth3a/

Comment: or `display: inline-block;` too, and I guess you need to correct understoor to *understood* ;)

Comment: Thank you soo much! it works!
I just wonder why it did not work when I add `display:inline-block;` to `.nav li a{}` or `.nav{}`   :|

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add `display: inline-block;` to your `li`

Possible duplication of [Why is my bootstrap navbar not displaing inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365057/why-is-my-bootstrap-navbar-not-displaing-inline)

Comment: same answer by @Shtut

Comment: and this is not duplicate because OP didn't mention bootstrap anywhere

Comment: :D... ok sir... may be that answer was posted while i was reading this question... will delete this if you dint like ;)

Comment: This is not about like or dislike, you can modify it better if you think your answer is better ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]    hi friend;

```
You just make 

.nav li{display:inline-block;}

and remove .nav li a {display: inline;}

see attachment file....[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```